# My application crashes when I use OnClicklistener for button even when it is empty

Tags: android

My activity is this one, this is LogInActivity which uses layout with same name, when I add the action listeners for the buttons , the application crashes
please help me out this is happening from last two days

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class LogInActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button signUpButton;
    private Button logInButton;
    private Intent signUpChoiceIntent;
    private OnClickListener signupListener;
    private HumLogController humLogController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setIntentAndButton();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
   }

    private void setIntentAndButton(){
        signUpChoiceIntent = new Intent (this , SignUpChoiceActivity.class);
        signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstSignupButton);
        logInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstLoginButton);
        signupListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        };
        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(signupListener);
    }

}
```

Layout file, two button are creating all the problem:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LogInActivity"
    android:background="#ff0aff62"
    android:id="@+id/logInRelativeLayout">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logInUsernameField"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:hint="@string/username_field_hint_text"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="40" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/logInPasswordField"
        android:hint="@string/password_field_hint_text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="15" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_button_text"
        android:id="@+id/firstLoginButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="226dp"
        android:background="#fff54d70"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_button_text"
        android:id="@+id/firstSignupButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="376dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="#ff0aff62"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/or_text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstLoginButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="306dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="136dp"/>

//I am not missing the /relative layout closing tag, it is just not here
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.praduman.humlog/com.example.praduman.humlog.LogInActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.praduman.humlog.LogInActivity.setIntentAndButton(LogInActivity.java:41)
        at com.example.praduman.humlog.LogInActivity.onCreate(LogInActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the error? StackTrace please!

Comment: The signupListener i.e. when the new OnClickListener is made , everything crashes, even it is empty

Comment: I know it crashes, but post the LogCat output!

Comment: put setIntentAndButton(); after setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

Comment: Yeah it works , when I put setIntentAndButton() after setContentView();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class LogInActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private Button signUpButton;
        private Button logInButton;
        private Intent signUpChoiceIntent;
        private OnClickListener signupListener;
        private HumLogController humLogController;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
            setIntentAndButton();
       }

        private void setIntentAndButton(){
            signUpChoiceIntent = new Intent (this , SignUpChoiceActivity.class);
            signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstSignupButton);
            logInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstLoginButton);
            signupListener = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("clicked");
                }
            };
            signUpButton.setOnClickListener(signupListener);
        }

    }
```

Comment: if it helped you, please mark my answer as correct or upvote atleast.thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setIntentAndButton();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
}
```

Should be:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    setIntentAndButton();
}
```

The reason is that if you do not set the content view resource, all the findViewByID methods will return null.

You can also shorten this:

```
signupListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };
signUpButton.setOnClickListener(signupListener);
```

to this:

```
signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };
);
```

Comment: @PradumanRaparia please consider upvoting the answer! Have a nice day!

Comment: @PradumanRaparia just pinging you so you can see how you can simplify your code a tiny bit more!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `setIntentAndButton()` - which is where you hook up the listeners - before you call `setContentView()`. Thus, the buttons have not been created when you try to attach the listeners, and the calls to `findViewById` will return `null`. You need to create your view before you try to manipulate the objects in it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    setIntentAndButton();
}
```